# Why all the directories of my laravel application is indexed in google?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, web-hosting, google-search, google-index

My application is in `Laravel + Vue` I'v hosted on `Hostinger VPS ubuntu 20`.
when I type my site in Google like **mywebsite.com** google showing all the directories.

This is my site config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mywebsite.com
   ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
   ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mywebsite/public

   <Directory /var/www/html/mywebsite>
        AllowOverride All
        Options -Indexes
        Require all granted
        ReWriteEngine On
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mywebsite.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mywebsite.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone know What I'm missing in the configuration.

for the ssl I use Letsencypt cerbot.

Answer (score 1):

Your web server is configured to show directory indexes.  That shows a web page with a list of files for directory requests when the directory does not contain an index document.  You can disable this by using

```
Options -Indexes
```

That can either go beneath `AllowOverride All` or in your `.htaccess` file.  If you make changes to your Apace configuration files, you will need to restart Apache or tell it to reload its conf files before they take effect.

Another workaround is to create blank `index.html` files in each directory that is currently showing the file listing. Search engines will treat that as a "soft 404" error which will prevent it from getting indexed.

After making changes, test that you can't browse those directories and see the file listing anymore.  Then you will have to wait a couple weeks for Googlebot to recrawl those pages and stop indexing them.

Comment: Hi Stephen, Options -Indexes did not work, it is more than a month I waited still google shows my directories. I updated my question and added the .htaccess content, if you could see. thanks.

Comment: Have you tested your site? If you visit the directories in a browser do you get an error now?

Comment: No, I do no get any error when click on one of the indexes shows all the files and directories exist inside like I attached a screenshot at the end of my question. If you type exptradies.com in Google you will definitely see what I mean.

Comment: For some reason `-Indexes` is not taking effect.  I can't tell exactly what it is from what you posted.  Mohammed pointed out one weird thing:  `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/exptradies/public` and `<Directory /var/www/html/exptradies>` don't match.  The should have the same path.    I would also recommend taking the `IfModule` conditions out of your `.htaccess`.  Unless you are planning to put your site on a server that might not have those modules and your site would work OK without them, then you shouldn't be testing for them.

Comment: I added another possible workaround to my answer.

Comment: I use certBot free ssl service provider, this is not the only laravel app I'm hosted on a vps, my other apps do not have this issue.

Comment: The apache configuration you posted is only for `<VirtualHost *:80>` which is not HTTPS, where is your `<VirtualHost *:443> configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Add public to your path in Directory and this probably will solve your problem

```
<Directory /var/www/html/exptradies/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        Require all granted
        ReWriteEngine On
   </Directory>
```

Don't forget to restart apache service

Comment: hosein, Thanks for your reply, adding public to the Directory tag did not solve, I tried that, This is not the only Laravel project I have hosted, I do not have this problem in my other websites, it's kind of unusual to me.